# Why is my multithreaded parser not multithreading?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree, python-multithreading

I have a script that parses xml files using the ElementTree Path Evaluator. It works fine as it is, but it takes a long for it to finish. So I tried to make a multithreaded implementation:

```
import fnmatch
import operator
import os
import lxml.etree
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import Queue

STOPWORDS = stopwords.words('dutch')
STOPWORDS.extend(stopwords.words('english'))
DIR_NAME = 'A_DIRNAME'
PATTERN = '*.A_PATTERN'

def loadData(dir_name, pattern):
    nohyphen_files = []
    dir_names = []
    dir_paths = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_name):
        dir_names.append(dirnames)
        dir_paths.append(root)
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, pattern):
            nohyphen_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return nohyphen_files, dir_names, dir_paths

def freq(element_list, descending = True):
    agglomerated = defaultdict(int)
    for e in element_list:
        agglomerated[e] += 1
    return sorted(agglomerated.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=descending)

def lexDiv(amount_words):
    return 1.0*len(set(amount_words))/len(amount_words)

def anotherFreq(list_types, list_words):
    fd = FreqDist(list_types)
    print 'top 10 most frequent types:'
    for t, freq in fd.items()[:10]:
        print t, freq
    print '\ntop 10 most frequent words:'
    agglomerated = defaultdict(int)
    for w in list_words:
        if not w.lower() in STOPWORDS:
            agglomerated[w] += 1
    sorted_dict = sorted(agglomerated.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    print sorted_dict[:10]

def extractor(f):
    print "check file: {}".format(f)
    try:
        # doc = lxml.etree.ElementTree(lxml.etree.XML(f))
        doc = lxml.etree.ElementTree(file=f)
    except lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError, e:
        print e
        return
    doc_evaluator = lxml.etree.XPathEvaluator(doc)
    entities = doc_evaluator('//entity/*/externalRef/@reference')
    places_dbpedia = doc_evaluator('//entity[contains(@type, "Schema:Place")]/*/externalRef/@reference')
    non_people_dbpedia = set(doc_evaluator('//entity[not(contains(@type, "Schema:Person"))]'))
    people = doc_evaluator('//entity[contains(@type, "Schema:Person")]/*/externalRef/@reference')
    words = doc.xpath('text/wf[re:match(text(), "[A-Za-z-]")]/text()',\
        namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
    unique_words = set(words)
    other_tokens = doc.xpath('text/wf[re:match(text(), "[^A-Za-z-]")]/text()',\
        namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
    amount_of_sentences = doc_evaluator('text/wf/@sent')[-1]
    types = doc_evaluator('//term/@morphofeat')
    longest_sentence = freq(doc.xpath('text/wf[re:match(text(), "[A-Za-z-]")]/@sent',\
        namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}))[0]

    top_people = freq([e.split('/')[-1] for e in people])[:10]
    top_entities = freq([e.split('/')[-1] for e in entities])[:10]
    top_places = freq([e.split('/')[-1] for e in places_dbpedia])[:10]

def worker():
    while 1:
        job_number = q.get()
        extractor(job_number)
        q.task_done() #this thread is complete, move on

if __name__ =='__main__':
    startTime = datetime.now()
    files, dirs, path = loadData(DIR_NAME, PATTERN)
    startTime = datetime.now()

q = Queue.Queue()# job queue

for f in files:
    q.put(f)

for i in range(20): #make 20 workerthreads ready
    worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    worker_thread.daemon = True
    worker_thread.start()

q.join()
print datetime.now() - startTime
```

This does something, but when timing it, it isn't faster than the normal version. I think it has something to do with opening and reading files making the threader not multithreaded. If I use a function that instead of parsing the xml file just sleeps for a couple of second and prints something, it does work and it is a lot faster. What do I have to account for to have a multithreaded XML parser?

Comment: using `threading` only makes parallelisation of the code you've written. It doesn't actually make it go across cores in the CPU (correct me if I'm wrong here). And also reading from a single drive will be a bottle-neck since well the disk itself can only handle so much I/O at one given time. You can gain a few seconds even minutes at best from parellizing (?!?) your code. What you need is a better storage volume and probably a caching mechanism for faster reading. Try reading the files into RAM or a DB as a cache first if possible and then work with them. Or RAID your disks.

Comment: @Torxed it's not my goal to make it go across cores in the CPU. A parallelisation is my goal, the point that I'm trying to make is that running a function that does some kind of parsing makes the whole programming blocking. So suppose the function extractor just sleeps for a second and prints something then it works, but when parsing a xml file it does't work in a paralleled manner. Do you know if it has to do with the XPathEvaluator and if there's a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Threading in Python doesn't work as it does in other languages. It relies on the Global Interpreter Lock that makes sure only one thread is active at one time (running bytecode to be exact).
What you want to do is use the multiprocess library, instead.
You can read more about the GIL and Threading here:
https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: It would be cheaper for the system to instantiate threads instead of processes. The only thing I want to do is something which can be viewed as a multithreaded web crawler. What I am doing can be seen as collecting the paths to files as collecting urls and parallelise my code to execute the same function on a different file simultaneously. 

So I don't understand why a function such as sleeping for two seconds and then print something would work by multithreading and parsing an XML file wouldn't. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @Soufyan Belkaid Executing bytecode in Python can be simplified by saying any operation you do, such as basic object manipulation, is done in the active thread while the rest are waiting for their turn, to do their own basic object manipulations. Any thread in your process that needs to wait will give way to another thread to continue executing. Reasoning against real threads `because performance suffered in the common single-processor case. It is believed that overcoming this performance issue would make the implementation much more complicated and therefore costlier to maintain.`